# Why is Context.User null on ASP.NET Master Page now?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I just swiched to a new ASP.NET host and it seems it is behaving differently. In the code for the master page it is attempting too do some different logic for authenticated users by this.

```
if (Context.User.IsAuthenticated) {
}
```

But the Context.User object is null. But it's only null on the master page. If I use it on the regular page it works.

```
if (User.IsAuthenticated) {
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? I might not have much control over the hosting environment but is there a different way I can get this information in the master page?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**:

It seems that the Context.User or Page.User object is null in both

- Dashboard.aspx (which users the master page Page.master) AND
- Page.master

But it is not null in

- TestUser.aspx (which does not use any master page)

Comment: Where are you making this check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
Page.User.IsAuthenticated
```

on the master page?

Comment: I have since moved away from this application and finished the MVC version of the site so this problem is no longer an issue. I didn't realize you could use Page.User.IsAuthenticated so this did help me out.

Answer (score 3):

try this One:
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated